# Why Multiple File Upload Is Not Working?

Tags: php, yii, multifile-uploader, cmultifileupload

I have tried so many ways to make multiple file upload workable using CMultiFileUpload widget. Already,  I have checked and followed below links-

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47665-multiple-file-upload/

[Yii multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179660/yii-multiple-file-upload)

BUT still no luck!!

Here is my code:

View:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'images-form',
'method'=>'post',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'enableClientValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
 )); ?>

<?php
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
'model'=>$model,
'name'=>'image_filename',
'attribute'=>'image_filename',
'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
'options'=>array(
    // 'onFileSelect'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("onFileSelect - "+v) }',
    // 'afterFileSelect'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("afterFileSelect - "+v) }',
    // 'onFileAppend'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("onFileAppend - "+v) }',
    // 'afterFileAppend'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("afterFileAppend - "+v) }',
    // 'onFileRemove'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("onFileRemove - "+v) }',
    // 'afterFileRemove'=>'function(e, v, m){ alert("afterFileRemove - "+v) }',
),
'denied'=>'File is not allowed',
'max'=>10,
'htmlOptions' => array( 'multiple' => 'multiple'),
));
?>

<div class="row buttons">
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Add' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Controller:

When I use GET method to see the form submit functionality then I found its displaying file name after submission. But, using POST method I did not see the name inside `if(isset($_POST['Images']))`. Even I failed see echo result inside there.

```
public function actionPhoto()
{            
  $model=new Images;
  if(isset($_POST['Images']))
  {
    echo 1;//Test purpose. Not displaying after form submission!!

    $model->attributes=$_POST['Images'];

    $image_filename = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image_filename');

    // proceed if the images have been set
    if (isset($image_filename) && count($image_filename) > 0)
    {
        // go through each uploaded image
        foreach ($image_filename as $image_filename => $pic)
        {
            echo $pic->name.'<br />';//Check purpose

            if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/'.$pic->name))
            {  
                $Images = new Images();
                $Images->image_filename = $pic->name;

                $Images->save();
            }
        }
    }
}

$this->render('photo',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Model rules:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    array('image_filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, png, gif','allowEmpty'=>false, 'on'=>'insert'),       
    array('id, image_filename', 'safe'),
    array('id, image_filename', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
);
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks for your help & kind co-operation.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, change below line

```
$image_filename = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('$image_filename');
```

to

```
$image_filename = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image_filename');
```

Comment: Yes, In my post it should be only attribute name without variable sign. I have updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: What is the result after updating code? same situation or any results?

Comment: Same situation. Noting displaying inside if(isset($_POST['Images']))

Comment: add print_r($_POST) details in quesyion.

Comment: Its showing "Array ( [yt0] => Add )" after form submission. Same showing for single image attachment or multiple image attachment.

Comment: then you did you check `print_r($_FILES);`. Add print_r($_FILES) result array in your code

Comment: Its displaying "Array ( [user_filename] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => logo.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php2413.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 15965 ) ) ) " for one image.

Comment: echo $pic->name.'<br />' printing your image name?

Comment: echo $pic->name.'<br />' printing your image name? Yes